# Doubt about coding and channels in "Elements of Information Theory" by Cover and Thomas

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I'll refer to the book by Cover and Thomas "Elements of Information Theory". In particular the definition of discrete channel, at page 183. I think I am making some confusion about what's going on here.

So, basically one wants to be able to transmit a message $W$ from a sender $A$ t a receiver $B$. A channel is a triple $(\mathcal{X}, p(y|X), \mathcal{Y})$ where $\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y}$ are a collections of sympols and $p(y|x)$ is a probability matrix such giving the conditional probability of receiving the signal $y$ if the signal $x$ was sent. So far so good. After this he defines the code for a canal $(\mathcal{X}^n, p(y^n|x^n), \mathcal{Y}^n)$ ($n-$tuples of symbols) as:

- A set of indices $A=\{1, \dots, M\}$ , i.e. the message you want to transmit;
- An encoding function $X^n : A \to \mathcal{X}^n$
- A decoding function $g :\mathcal{Y}^n \to A$

Now, he talks about distributions of $X^n, Y^n$ etc. And mathematically speaking, I get it. But I think I am missing the basic idea here. My intuition is that you have a message $W$, you encode it in some DETERMINISTIC way, you transfer it (and here there might be issues/errors/randomness) and you decode it again deterministically. What is the meaning of $X^n (1)$ for instance? You should have that $X^n (1)= x^n (1)$, i.e you are assigning a particular string of n letters from your alphabet $\mathcal{X}$ to the message $1$. But then what does it mean the probability ditribution of $X^n$? Where's the randomness?

Also, in Chapter 5 he talks about compression of data with "source codes", which is basically a mapping from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{D}^*$, some strings of another alphabet of symbols (typically $\{0,1\}$). Now, how does in practice this come into play here? Because in the chapter about channels it is not mentioned. If I understood correctly, what happens "in reality" is:

- You want to send a message $ W \in A$
- You encode the message with $X^n : A \to \mathcal{X}^n$
- You compress the encoded message with a deterministic function $C^* : \mathcal{X}^n \to D^*$
- You transmit the compressed data through the channel
- Decompress and decode the received signal

and maybe in the book the compressing/decompressing part was skipped to make things clearer. Am I right?

Comment: The randomness is that you usually think of the message $W$ as being a random variable that takes values uniformly over the set $\{1, ..., M\}$.

Comment: People usually separate coding for data compression from coding for communication over a channel.  I would describe the typical view as backwards from what you describe: You have a source (say, a text file) with lots of redundancy, so you compress it (think of running "compress" on your laptop to create a smaller file).  Intuitively, the compressed data now looks like a string of i.i.d. equally likely bits, which is the assumption that is typically used for channel coding, so then you channel-code on those (roughly) i.i.d. compressed bits. Then send.  Then channel-decode.  Then source-decode.

Comment: Regarding your first question (on randomness in channel coding). The randomness only applies to the generation of the "codebook". The codebook, i.e., the $M$ codewords $X^m(1), X^n(2),\dots, X^n(M)$, is generated randomly from scratch, according to some distribution (ideally, the one that achieves the channel capacity). Once the codebook has been generated, it is made known to both transmitter and receiver and remains fixed.

Comment: @Michael but then wht would be the distribution of $X^n$? Because the way it is explained, it's distribution is assumed to be $p(x^n)= \prod _i=1 ^n p(x_i)$, with $x^n=x_1 x_2 \dots x_n$ a codeword. I mean if you have a deterministic $X^n$ and the randomness comes from the choice of messages only, then I am not sure how you can break down the probability distribution like that. For example, $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ is the set of messages and $X^3$ goes to strings $100,101,110,111$. Then $p(x_1=1)= 1$, $p(x_2=1)=1/2$ and $p(x_3=1)=1/2$ right? So for example $p(x_i=1)=$ times you have 1/total cases?

Comment: @Stelios if I get what you say, you are giving $X^n$ a probability density and then let it generate the codewords. But then couldn't they be redundant? Let's say I have $X^3 : A \to \{0,1}^3$ and a set of messages $A=\{1,2,3,4,\}$. Let $X^3$ have the distribution $p(x_1x_2 x_3)= p(x_1)p(x_2)p(x_3)$ with $p(x_1=1)=p(x_2=1)=p(x_3)=1/2$ , so that the probability of having a symbol doesn't depend on the position. Then why couldn't I have $X^3 (1)= 111$ and $X^2 =111$ too? They both have probability 1/8, so couldn't  it be that when generating the code I get same codewords from different messages?

Comment: @Michael of course there's a typo in the comment above, you should have $\prod_{i=1} ^n p(x_i)$

Comment: If you have 4 equally likely codewords $\{(0,0,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,1), (1,1,0)\}$ then the marginal distribution of each bit that is sent is Bernoulli-1/2.  For example if the random codeword sent is $(Y_1, Y_2, Y_3)$ then $P[Y_i=0]=P[Y_i=1]=1/2$ for each $i \in \{1,2,3\}$.  The joint mass function is of course $P[(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)=(0,0,0)]=P[(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)=(0,1,0)]=...=1/4$. In this example it also holds that $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ are pairwise independent (but not mutually independent).

Comment: @tommy1996q With very large codewords (which is the regime the theorem applies to), the probability of this happening is asymptotically small. In case it indeed happens, you would discard this codebook and generate a new one (that has distinct codewords)

Comment: Yeah looking at the proof of the channel coding theorem they do exactly that, so that's taken into account and has a very small probability of happening